# Why doesn't this function remove all periods from these dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a python dictionary with a number of key:value pairs. Some of these keys contain a period `.`, like so:

```
record = {"a.a":1, "b..b":2, "c......":3, ".d.d.d":4, ".e.e.e.":5}
```

Now, I want to remove all periods from all keys in this dictionary. In order to do that, I have the following code:

```
for property in record:
    record[property.translate({ord('.'): None})] = record.pop(property)
```

However, what I end up with is this:

```
{'b..b': 2, 'eee': 5, 'aa': 1, 'c': 3, 'ddd': 4}
```

Notice the unchanged `b..b`.

Why does this happen? If I call the same block of code again, the extra periods *are* removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do here is changing the dictionary while iterating over it, that's so not good.

`{k.replace('.', ''): v for k, v in record.items()}` 
will do your work just fine.